# Ansible when json_query is undefined

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a structure like this:

```
domain_definition:
  domain:
    cluster:
         name: "cluster1"
         params: 
            - 30
    server:
         name: "server1"
         params: 
            - 30
            - 20
            - 10
```

And I run this handler

```
- name: restart
  shell: ...
  async: 45 
  poll: 0 
  with_subelements:
   - "{{domain_definition|json_query('domain.*')| default([])}}"
   - params
  listen: "restart"
```

In some hosts domain_definition is not defined, so I try to add

```
  when: domain_definition is defined
```

But I get

```
 "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\n'domain_definition' is undefined"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some jinja2 and jmspath I solved like this:

```
with_subelements:
  - "{{domain_definition| default({'domain':{}}) | json_query('domain.*')}}"
  - params
```

It looks up for domain_definition, since it doesn't exists sets default value to "{'domain':{}}". Then json_query receives that value and process it. As it's an empty object, it just skips the whole task.

I believe this is a bug, on the "with_subelements" and "when" condition . On ansible 2.2 it used to work, I upgraded to 2.4 and it isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. With looped tasks `when` is applied to every iteration after loop arguments are parsed.
2. All vars manipulations should be done **inside** `{{...}}` instead of `{{...}}|default(...)`.

But I guess you actually want:

```
with_subelements:
  - "{{domain_definition|json_query('domain.*')}}"
  - params
  - skip_missing: yes
```

Comment: Yes, wrong copy paste on number 2. And skip_missing doesn't work, doc says: "Optionally, you can add a third element to the subelements list, that holds a dictionary of flags. Currently you can add the ‘skip_missing’ flag. If set to True, the lookup plugin will skip the lists items that do not contain the given subkey. ".

Comment: The problem is that there is no domain_definition at all on the host vars.